# C#: Restrict how a console app can be called

Tags: c#, console-application

We have a product that is a C# console app. Is it possible to restrict it to run from the  command line only? In other words, users wouldn't be able to call it from a script or another app.

If it is, some example code would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really mean the DOS command line(command.com), or the NT command line(cmd.exe)? Or is any console application fine?

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to prevent other programs from starting your program?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Good points. Any console app is fine. I would like to prevent the app being used as part of another product or service.

Comment: It's pointless, anybody can fool you with "cmd.exe /c yourapp.exe".

Comment: Not to mention that if you launch a process and immediately exit, the process is 'orphaned', it has no parent.

Comment: p.s. DOS died with Windows ME. There is no "DOS command line".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the process that created your application using the code given here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569609.aspx#Question3 . To be started at the DOS command line the parent process should be cmd.exe. Note however as pointed out by Colin this can be bypassed easily using a batch script. You can disable that as well by making sure that the command prompt arguments to cmd.exe are null. For this you will need to use WMI : 
http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/04/11/using-wmi-to-fetch-the-command-line-that-started-all.aspx

You should also check the cmd.exe image is from system32 folder.

Comment: What's the parent process if the application was started from a batch script?

Comment: @Colin: Script host, I guess. Isn't it? e.g. WSH

Comment: @Basarat Ali. How do I check the arguments to cmd.exe are null? Thank you.

Comment: @swisstony You will need to use WMI for that. Updated post :)

Comment: @Basarat Ali. I tried that but GetCommandLines("cmd.exe") retuned the same value when run from the command line or called from a bat file:                            "cmd.exe" /k cd C:\dev\myapp\bin\Release

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to tell the difference.

Certainly the parent process is not a useful indicator.  This is what you get in the parent process:

```
1. type app name into Command Prompt:     cmd.exe
2. call app from batch script:            cmd.exe
3. Double click on app or shortcut:       explorer.exe
4. type app name into Run dialog box:     explorer.exe
```

If you intend for 1. to be a valid way to start your program, then I don't think you can stop 2. which means your app can be called from any script or any program (since it's simple for another program to create a 1 line batch script and execute it)

(BTW, does anyone know a way to get a table on StackOverflow?)

Comment: Is there anyway of finding the grandparent? Then you could check if cmd.exe was spawned by something you expect rather than a script or unknown process?

Comment: There are more ways to start a process, Task Manager -> File -> Run comes to mind, I'm sure there are more that don't come to mind.

Comment: Oh yeah, these were only meant as examples.  Task Scheduler would be another one.

Answer (score 1):

@swisston if you start your console application from your another own application, than i want to recommend you "named kernel objects". For example mutex. You can create named mutex in your parent app. Then in main thread of your child console app try to open this mutex. If mutex not opened (not found): console app has no permissions to continue and must be closed;) *wait, i'll make some code for you;)*

**Edit:**
So it is very easy tactics. In parent app create your named mutex:

```
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyPermissions");
```

Then in your child console application check if your mutex exists:

```
    static bool CheckPermissions()
    {
        try
        {
            Mutex mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("MyPermissions");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

If your console application was run without your parent application CheckPermissions method will return false and console must be closed;)

Comment: This doesn't help since the parent app can be invoked from anywhere. You just moved the problem up one level without solving anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with what you're trying to do, but here is an idea that could work: require some sort of user input at the beginning of the program, maybe some sort of CAPTCHA (difficult to do in command line, but theoretically possible. Think ASCII art).